# Emulators and real my devices are different

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I lowered the version of android sdk while creating the app.
30 -> 26

So what works in an emulator doesn't work on my cell phone.
Let me know why.

emulator verison is 26 (It works well.)
[image]

but my real device is didnt work :(
(android sdk verison is 26 too)[image]

I think it's probably not a problem with Sdk.
It was the same before changing from 30 to 26.

my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Fetch(),
    );
  }
}

class Fetch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FetchState createState() => _FetchState();
}

class _FetchState extends State<Fetch> {
  //List<String> list = List();
  String txt = "";
  void _getData() async {
    String str = "https://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/yongwon-h/main.do#";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    //final elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

    //txt = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHtml.replaceAll("<span>", "").replaceAll("<"+"/"+"span>", "");
    txt = document
        .getElementsByClassName('meal_list')[0]
        .innerHtml
        .replaceAll("dietDiv;", "");
    print(txt);

    setState(() {
      print(txt);

      /*     list = elements
          .map((element) =>
       element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src'])
          .toList();*/
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              _getData();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '음식 / 알레르기 번호\n',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'cage',
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
                      child: Text(
                        txt,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'cage',
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              '만약 급식이 장시간동안 불러와 지지 않는다면, \n새로고침을 눌러주세요.',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'cage',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd place my bets on the positioned widget

Comment: It may be you're wrongly using expanded widget which is showing it's magic :D

Comment: how can i fix it??

Comment: some time emulator does not get performance and in real devices, you can find some of the specified issues test properly like cache image or internet image loading devices responsiveness and other things.....

Comment: thx i replace it